# Get login/logout info to all components/routes in React Router app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a poll app which allows users to create and vote on polls. It also has a login functionality. The problem is that I am handling login in a `<Top>` component (a Reactstrap `<Navbar>`), and the content of some components depends on if someone is signed in or not. If someone is not signed in and is at the `/polls/:pollnumber` url, for example, and then signs in, I need the content in `<Poll>` to update (e.g., they are allowed to vote on the poll instead of just seeing results). I can't figure out how to structure my app to make that work.

Here's my main Browser Router page

```
/* app.jsx */

const local = localStorage.getItem('poll-login');

if (local) {
  let info = JSON.parse(local);
  let loggedIn = true;
  let name = info.name;
  let token = info.token;
  let twitter_id = info.twitter_id;
};

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Top loggedIn={ loggedIn } name={ name } token={ token } />
      <Route exact path="/" component={ HelloWorld } />
      <Route exact path="/newpoll" component={ Newpoll } loggedIn={ loggedIn } name={ name } token={ token } />
      <Route exact path="/polls/:pollnumber" component={ Poll } loggedIn={ loggedIn } name={ name } token={ token } />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('main'));
```

When app first loads, I check localStorage to see if person was previously signed in, and pass that info to two of the child components. `<Top>` is a navbar and has a Twitter authentication strategy as one of its nav items, and the navbar will change based on whether the person is logged in or not (as I want).

As you can see, the navbar (`<Top>`) is rendered on every view. But if a user is not logged in and is at a path like `/newpoll` or `/polls/:pollnumber` and then the user logs in, the `<Top>` component's state will change (as I want), but not the others, and I want how they are rendered to be determined based on whether a user is logged in or not.

I tried `ComponentDidUpdate` in the other components but it does not fire when login/logout occurs on the `<Top>` component.

I'm new to React-Router but my understanding is there is no `state` in the main `<BrowserRouter>` file, so my understanding is I can't handle my login there and then pass state changes (such as a login) to child components. How can I structure my app so that these sibling components/routes are able to get login/logout info so they render as I want?

Answer (score 2):

In your case when you login at a path `/newpoll` there is no route change, that's why no update for Routes will be triggered.
Now you can select what implementation to use:

- Create a PrivatePage and a PublicPage component, and show them when user is logged in or out. This way PrivatePage childs will remount
- There is no state there, but you can create one, just render a component that will hold an auth state and control it with actions (redux, etc.)
- You can even put all your `Route`'s as a childs inside `Top` component, and show them only if user authed.
- Personally i like to do a wrapper for authorised routes, something along these lines:

*privateroute.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} 
/>
    )} />
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm sure it would work but I ended up using Redux as a solution

Comment: Yeah, fine choice :-)